# Google Sheets - Retrieve "A:File1" to "A:File2" where "Sheetname:File1" = "B:File2" if "C:File2" is between "E" and "F" in "File1"

Tags: import, google-sheets, concatenation, vlookup

Sorry for the somewhat long title, but I was told to be as specific as possible. :D

My problem will require some explantion.

So, I have 2 spreadsheets files ("**Konverteringstabeller**" and "**Tee Posen**").
In "**Tee Posen**" I have a sheet named "**Scores MIK**" (golf scorecard and my name).
In "**Konverteringstabeller**" I have sheets with conversion tables for multiple golf courses, but if one works, all should.

What I need is to find out what course handicap I would get if my golf handicap is "**HCP 26,0**" (as shown in File 2 Picture), and in this case that result should be 29 (not visible), but you should get the point.
*(example: golf hcp 10 would result in course hcp 11, because 10 is between 9,9-10,7)*

While I have been able to find the right result, it has only been in the "**Konverteringstabeller**" spreadsheet file and that is not the place I need it.
I want to have it written in **E6** in the "**Scores MIK**" sheet in File 2.

I should mention that in "**Scores MIK** : File 2", cell **C2** (Ikast Golf Klub) has data validation so I can easily change between the different courses in the "**Konverteringstabeller**" file once I add more.

What I have been messing with is something with vlookup and importrange with concatenate in it, but I can't figure out how to do it, so I ask for your help.

And I am by no means skilled in the art of Spreadsheets, so I would very much appreciate a detailed explanation.

[Picture - Scores MIK (File 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLdUl.png)
[Picture - Ikast Golf Klub (File 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GheDp.png)

Thanks in advance!
// Mikkel Christensen

Comment: can you share a sample spreadsheet and show what formula you are trying to write for  it - putting a description only is really difficult to correctly identify how your formula needs to be constructed

Comment: Ofcourse, I am sorry. It was very late when I posted and totally forgot. :)    =vlookup(G1;B8:E70;4) - is how I found the number I want, but this only works in FILE1, in FILE2 I have tried the following:    =ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(E5;IMPORTRANGE("sheet_key";CONCATENATE(C2;"!B8:E70;4");4;true)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so a couple notes - One is that to join a static cell where you keep the sheet name but allow it to chance you should add '$' around it, also if the rows for B8-E70 will always be the same position on the various sheets you also need to add $ around those as well.

here is an example of the whole formula

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(E5:E25;IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet key";"'"&C2&"'!$B$8:$E$70");4;TRUE)))
```

And lastly - using the "&" operator to concatenate is better at least in my opinion because concatenate sometimes does not work as well with array formula - plus I find it personally quicker and easier to use that having wrap yet another function around my stuff.

Comment: Did you hover over the ref and allow access also the  name of your sheet should include the ! After it..and lastly if your doing. It without the array formula  then just put e5

Comment: Also, yes, the information I need to retrive will always be on B8-E70.

Comment: Went back to #N/A.. I dont think I quite know what you mean by allow access on the #REF!, because when I hover it says that VLOOKUP is evalutated to a value outside of permitted interval.

Comment: Try entering in the entire sheet url instead of just the key - to make sure the access is set up properly to import the range just do the import range by itself first and make sure you get data back, then add it to the vlookup

Comment: If that doesn't work than can you share the actual spreadsheet temporarily so I can take a look

Comment: updated the answer - also if that is your actual source sheet you may want to edit your spreadsheet key to say "key" in your comment above @MikkelChristensen

Comment: Couldn't edit comments, so deleted them. But a HUUUGE thank you for all your help. I have also accepted your answer.